# Validar input, usando formbuilder, com pattern em angular 9

Tags: angular

Quero exibir a mensagem de erro quando o usuário alterar ou tornar o input ativo usando o pattern ^[\x20-\xFF]{5,50}$

Mas quando digito caracteres que não atendem o campo, o mesmo só fica vermelho e a mensagem de erro não aparece.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<form [formGroup]="ChannelCreateForm" (ngSubmit)="CreateChannel()">
  <mat-form-field class="input-full-width" appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>{{'channel.NewChannelPage.name' | transloco}}</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="ChannelTitle"> 
    <mat-hint align="start" *ngIf="ChannelTitle.errors?.pattern && (ChannelTitle.dirty || ChannelTitle.touched)" class="text-danger">inválido</mat-hint>
  <mat-hint align="end">{{titleInput.value.length}} / 50</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
    ....
</form>


Pattern50Char = "^[\x20-\xFF]{5,50}$";

  ChannelCreateForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    public _FormBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public _MatSnackBar: MatSnackBar
  ) { 
    this.ChannelCreateForm = this._FormBuilder.group({
      ChannelTitle: ['', [Validators.pattern(this.Pattern50Char), Validators.maxLength(50)]]
    });
  }

  get titleInput() {
    return this.ChannelCreateForm.get('ChannelTitle');
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu tentaria boa parte dessa validação no `component` e não via referência no template (seu #channelTitle). Primeiro alterando nos `Validators` do `FormBuilder` o pattern e o maxLength, e expondo a referência do title via `get`

```
myPattern = "^[\x20-\xFF]{5,50}$";

form: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    channelTitle: ["", [Validators.pattern(this.myPattern), Validators.maxLength(50)]]
  });
}

get titleInput() {
  return this.form.get('channelTitle');
}
```

No HTML ficaria assim, removeria o #channelTitle e usaria a referência do `get` criada, o `titleInput`:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="CreateChannel()">
   <mat-form-field class="input-full-width" appearance="standard">
   <mat-label>{{'channel.NewChannelPage.name' | transloco}}</mat-label>
   <input matInput type="text" formControlName="channelTitle"> 
   <mat-hint align="start" *ngIf="titleInput.errors?.pattern && (titleInput.dirty || titleInput.touched)">inválido</mat-hint>
   <mat-hint align="end">{{titleInput.value.length}} / 50</mat-hint>
 </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: Fiz as alterações e atualizei o post com as informações que você colocoou, mas a mensagem de erro continua não aparecendo, o campo fica vermelho quando perde o focus.. mas nada de mensagem.

Comment: @RRV no seu exemplo você ta referenciando o `channelTitle` no `*ngIf`, altera pra `titleInput` e me diz

Comment: Patrick.. obrigado, problema resolvido.

Comment: Patrick.. aproveitando pode tirar uma dúvida.. Quando inicio o grupo, considerando um form de atualização de dados, como faço para manter a informação que está no input? por exemplo não apagar o channelTitle channelTitle: [" ", [Validators.pattern(this.myPattern), Validators.maxLength(50)]]

Comment: @RRV não sei se entendi sua pergunta, você queria fazer um reset da informação?

Comment: Estava me referindo a iniciar campos com valores recuperados do BD. Fiz desta maneira -> this.UserNameForm.get('UserName').setValue(data.user_name) e funcionou.